# Question about "wp_deregister_script()"

Tags: functions

Should I always deregister script or not?

Right now I am using this:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'js_jqTransform', 20);
function js_jqTransform() {
    wp_register_script('jqTransform', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jqtransform/jqtransformplugin/jquery.jqtransform.js', false, null);
    wp_enqueue_script('jqTransform');
}
```

And my concern is if I should use it like this:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'js_jqTransform', 20);
function js_jqTransform() {
    wp_deregister_script('jqTransform');
    wp_register_script('jqTransform', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jqtransform/jqtransformplugin/jquery.jqtransform.js', false, null);
    wp_enqueue_script('jqTransform');
}
```

And if I should use always deregister then why?

Because I have noticed that some developers use for frontend something like this:

```
if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
function my_jquery_enqueue() {

    // JQuery
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js", false, null);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

}
```

What is the reason behind that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reasons behind this is that these developers are doing_it_wrong. You should never deregister the core version of jQuery and [here is why](http://pippinsplugins.com/why-loading-your-own-jquery-is-irresponsible/).

However wp_deregister_script has its place, for example in child themes when you want to deactive a script or enqueue your own script instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your very first snippet is fine. No modifications needed.

The last case you have come across, because jQuery is by default bundled with WordPress, as well as registered by the core.
*If*, which is not necessarily recommendable in the first place, you want to use an external source for jQuery - *then* you'd have to previously deregister the other version.